# iText Detect Text Overflow or Copy Fit

Tags: itext, itext7

I need to put some dynamic text onto a pdf.  I need to verify that the text does not overflow the boundary box I am allowed to use to place the text in.

- Is there a way to detect if this is happening?
- Are there any copy-fit rules that I can use to handle it when it does happen?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using iText5 or iText7? The tag itext usually refers to the former. Also, java or .Net? Both versions have some way of simulating the placement of content, but the answer depends on the version :)

Comment: *"I need to put some dynamic text onto a pdf"* - How shall that be done? Do you want to fill **AcroForm** text fields? Or do you want to add **FreeText** (**FreeTextTypeWriter**) annotations? Or do you want to add to the page **Contents** streams?

Comment: Define "dynamic text". Is it text that you don't know the length of before running your program? Or is it as mkl posts?

Comment: @SamuelHuylebroeck I haven't choosen a version yet, I would think since this is a new project I could use iText7.  It will be C#.

Comment: @mkl I'm not sure actually.  I am creating the PDF myself so I am available to do whatever works best.  The end result will be text on the page, not annotation.

Comment: @MichaëlDemey The text will come from a database so the length will vary with each run.

Answer (score 3):

`iText5` is in maintenance mode and I recommend that you start your project using `iText7`. `iText7` currently does not provide out of the box mechanisms for copy-fitting, but it can be done manually with little effort because layout engine is very flexible in `iText7`. Technically it can be done in `iText5` as well, but I will provide an answer for `iText7` for Java, and converting to C# shouldn't be a problem for you.

The basic idea is to make use of the Renderers concept and try yo layout your paragraph in the given area with different font sizes until you find the size which is OK for you. A binary search approach fits perfectly here.

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outFileName));
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

String text = "...";
Rectangle area = new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200);
// Just draw a black box around to verify the result visually
new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.addNewPage()).rectangle(area).setStrokeColor(Color.BLACK).stroke();

Paragraph p = new Paragraph(text);
IRenderer renderer = p.createRendererSubTree().setParent(doc.getRenderer());
LayoutArea layoutArea = new LayoutArea(1, area);

// lFontSize means the font size which will be definitely small enough to fit all the text into the box.
// rFontSize is the maximum bound for the font size you want to use. The only constraint is that it should be greater than lFontSize
// Set rFontSize to smaller value if you don't want the font size to scale upwards
float lFontSize = 0.0001f, rFontSize = 10000;

// Binary search. Can be replaced with while (Math.abs(lFontSize - rFontSize) < eps). It is a matter of implementation/taste
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    float mFontSize = (lFontSize + rFontSize) / 2;
    p.setFontSize(mFontSize);
    LayoutResult result = renderer.layout(new LayoutContext(layoutArea));
    if (result.getStatus() == LayoutResult.FULL) {
        lFontSize = mFontSize;
    } else {
        rFontSize = mFontSize;
    }
}

// lFontSize is guaranteed to be small enough to fit all the text. Using it.
float finalFontSize = lFontSize;
System.out.println("Final font size: " + finalFontSize);
p.setFontSize(finalFontSize);
// We need to layout the final time with the final font size set.
renderer.layout(new LayoutContext(layoutArea));
renderer.draw(new DrawContext(pdfDoc, new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.getPage(1))));

doc.close();
```

The output:

```
Final font size: 5.7393746
```

Visual result:

[image: The output PDF looks like this]